# How can I add time dimension in polar coordinates in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to plot with `ggplot2` the track of a bird around the antarctic. So far I got a map projected in polar coordinates, I also managed to plot the track points correctly and I almost link them correctly BUT... As the track crosses the international **DATE & TIME line** , `ggplot2` is not able to correctly link the 2 points in either sides of the line.So I'm looking for a way to force ggplot to link the points in continuous manner.

Here's my dataset:

```
Data =>
ID  Date      Time   A1   Lat.    Long.
10 12.9.2008 22:00   1  21.14092 70.98817 
10 12.9.2008 22:20   1  21.13031 70.97592 
10 12.9.2008 22:40   2  21.13522 70.97853 
10 12.9.2008 23:00   1  21.13731 70.97817
10 12.9.2008 23:20   3  21.14197 70.97981
10 12.9.2008 23:40   1  21.14156 70.98158
10 12.9.2008 23:40   1  21.14156 70.98158
10 13.9.2008 00:00   2  21.14150 70.98478
10 13.9.2008 00:20   3  21.14117 70.98803
10 13.9.2008 00:40   1  21.14117 70.98803
10 13.9.2008 01:00   2  21.14117 70.98803

....
```

ID is the bird's ID.

**UPDATE using Nick K code**

Here's my original graph without using the time dimension and line

```
south_map <- map_data("world") %>% group_by(group) 
set.seed(123)

track_df2 <- new_df2

long_diff <- diff(new_df2$Long)
long_diff[long_diff < -180] <- long_diff[long_diff < -180] + 360
long_diff[long_diff > 180] <- long_diff[long_diff > 180] - 360
track_df2$Longitude <- cumsum(c(new_df2$Long[1], long_diff))

ggplot(track_df2, aes(x = track_df2$Long, y = track_df2$Lat)) +
geom_polygon(aes(group = a3_id), data = south_map, colour = "grey", fill = "gainsboro") +
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(a3_id)), size = 2)
```

A1 defines what the bird is currently doing.

[image]

Comment: Just connect the points based on sorted time?

Comment: agree with @Vlo, I think you have to just convert the times. neat problem

Comment: @VIo I didn't get you. Can you give me some example or explain me?

Comment: @ayush I made a mistake in suggesting that, my apology. Your problem seems similar to (identical?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157221/ggplot2-how-to-link-correctly-track-points-around-polar-projection-map is this a homework? I would suggest maybe email ggplot package maintainer

Comment: @TanDollars No, its not a homework. I have a similar dataset and trying to do kindda similar stuff. That 1st image was taken as an example from that ques only but the second graph is from my original dataset and for that I have used the said command.

Comment: my primary recommendation is to email the package maintainer, but maybe you can 'trick' the desired output by reversing your data? That seems suboptimal, though

Comment: I would **not** recommend emailing the package maintainer, SO is a good forum for this type of question but the ggplot Google group is another option. What you can do to get an answer is to make a small, reproducible example. You share one data set but don't provide code to graph it, then you show code a graphs for a different data set. Let's see data and graph code *for that data*, and share the data using `dput()` for reproducibility.

Comment: @Frank I hope this helps now?
code for producing the graph is given at the bottom of the question

Comment: Your graph code doesn't match the data shared, and the data isn't shared with `dput(data)`. We don't need all your data, just enough to illustrate your problem which probably means going at least one full circle around the pole.

Comment: @Gregor Is it sufficient now?

Comment: @ayush, you still have not shared the data using `dput`. Please refer to [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ayush you can test yourself if it's sufficient: start a brand new R session, and run your code. Does it work? The answer is no, because you use some data frame called `new_df2` that you never define. Now try the same for Nick's answer: works just fine!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't seem to actually use the time in your plot, but the issue is the longitudes wrapping around -180/180. This can be solved using `coord_map` rather than `coord_polar` and ensuring that the longitudes don't wrap around.

Load packages and generate sample data

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
south_map <- map_data("world") %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(min(lat) <= -20)

set.seed(123)
track <- data.frame(long = cumsum(c(210,
                                    unlist(lapply(c(1, -1), function(x) {
                                      rnorm(50, x * 4, 4)
                                      })))) %% 360 - 180,
                    lat = cumsum(c(-50, rnorm(100, 0.4, 2))),
                    A1 = sample(1:3, 101, replace = TRUE))
```

Ensure that coordinates don't wrap around:

```
track_new <- track
long_diff <- diff(track$long)
long_diff[long_diff < -180] <- long_diff[long_diff < -180] + 360
long_diff[long_diff > 180] <- long_diff[long_diff > 180] - 360
track_new$long <- cumsum(c(track$long[1], long_diff))
```

Plot using aziequidistant projection. Note that this assumes the North Pole in the centre, so the latitudes are flipped and then corrected with the scale.

```
ggplot(track_new, aes(x = long, y = -lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), data = south_map, colour = "grey", fill = "gainsboro") +
  coord_map("azequidistant") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(A1)), size = 2) +
  geom_path(colour = "grey", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous("latitude", breaks = 25 * 0:3, labels = -25 * 0:3)
```

Final plot:

[image: Bird plot]

Just for interest, I thought it would be fun to produce an animation of this image. Here's the code to do it:

```
track_new$alpha <- 1
# Setup longitude labels

long_labels <- data.frame(long = 45 * -3:4, lat = -22.5)
long_labels$label <- long_labels$long
long_labels$label[8] <- "\U00B1 180"
long_labels$angle <- long_labels$long + 67.5 + 180 * (long_labels$long >= 45)

# Set up the basic plot
p <- ggplot(track_new, aes(x = long, y = -lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), data = south_map, colour = "grey", fill = "gainsboro") +
  coord_map("azequidistant", ylim = c(20, 90)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = A1, alpha = alpha), size = 2) +
  geom_path(aes(alpha = alpha), colour = "grey", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous("latitude", breaks = 22.5 * 0:3, labels = -22.5 * 0:3) +
  scale_alpha_identity(guide = "none") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, angle = angle),
            data = long_labels, colour = "dark blue", alpha = 0.5, size = 4)

# Produce the animation
p$data$alpha <- 0
for(i in 1:(nrow(track_new) + 10)) {
  p$data$alpha <- pmax(p$data$alpha - 0.1, 0)
  if (i <= nrow(track_new)) {
    p$data$alpha[i] <- 1
  }
  png(file.path("BirdPlots", sprintf("BirdPlot%03d.png", i)), width = 1024, height = 1024, res = 100)
  print(p)
  dev.off()
  if (!(i %% 5)) cat(i, "\n")
}

# This needs ImageMagick in the system path. For non-Windows systems, you
# might be better using system rather than shell
shell(paste("convert", file.path("BirdPlots", "BirdPlot*.png"),
  file.path("BirdPlots", "BirdPlotAnimation.gif")))
```

And here's the result:

[image: Animation of bird]

**EDIT** Corrected version of ayush's code

```
track_df2 <- new_df2

long_diff <- diff(new_df2$Longitude)
long_diff[long_diff < -180] <- long_diff[long_diff < -180] + 360
long_diff[long_diff > 180] <- long_diff[long_diff > 180] - 360
track_df2$Longitude <- cumsum(c(new_df2$Longitude[1], long_diff))

track_df2$a3_id <- factor(track_df2$a3_id)

ggplot(track_df2, aes(x = Longitude, y = -Latitude)) +
  coord_map("azequidistant", ylim = c(20, 90)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = a3_id, alpha = alpha), size = 2) +
  geom_path(aes(alpha = alpha), colour = "grey", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 22.5 * 0:3, labels = -22.5 * 0:3) +
  scale_alpha_identity(guide = "none")
```

Comment: I've added an animated version which produces a series of PNGs and converts them to an animated GIF.

Comment: Its a nice solution. But  the said problem is about adding the date & time feature. 

Yes, I didn't use the D & T in my plot because I can't find sol for this. Can you add Time as 3rd Dimension then plot the result? What the problem I am facing it is after 23:59:59 hrs time is reset to 00:00:00. Hence it's making layers. I want to preserve this 2D plot in 3D. 

Can you solve this problem?

Comment: @ayush I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want a 3d scatter plot effectively, with time represented as the height? Or something else? What have you tried so far? It's also worth noting that your original data was all between 70.9 and 71 degrees longitude, so the polar projection you've got looks way off.

Comment: @ayush You also wouldn't cross the dateline with those coordinates (and probably not even a timezone boundary). If it's just a time issue, surely you'd want the time dimension to be based on a fixed timezone - it doesn't really make sense to use local time.

Comment: Yes, as you stated in your 1st line. I don't want it to be in Scatterplot. I want  similar to polar coordinates to project Lat - Long - Time..
But the problem is as I said Its forming layes as the time is moving and its not giving me any good results out of it. 
Can you help me in this, I am still new in R.....?  I have tried looking Dygraphs but its not very helpful also its not ploting as the map/polar coordinates does

Comment: I still don't get how you want the third dimension plotted. The options in general are to use a 3d representation (e.g. rgl), something like a colour gradient (as seen in a heat map) or animation (like my second example). What do you want to achieve? Note that you can still use polar coordinates for a 3d scatter plot - you just need to transform them to cartesian coordinates first using `cos` and `sin`.

Comment: What I want to measure via the plot is that I want to see at what time what's my lat-long is? Also I want to analyze the path of the bird in the same graph (As you have done). Can you help with this part?
Your animation plot is way more helpful to me. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: @ayush so do you want the time printed on the graph as a label? Or a 3d graph? For the former it would be straightforward to use `geom_text` to print times. For the latter, as suggested above `plot3d`. Another option would be to create an animation that was effectively in sped-up realtime and being able to step through it.

Comment: What your last sugession is what I needed and is very effective too. 

I can't use geom_text because my dataset is too large and dense(in thousands). so I don't see It as a very good idea when I visualize my plot. (But yeah! its what is solving the problem)

plot3d/scatterplot isn't giving me good analysis. It is forming layers at time axis when I am using scatterplot3D which I don't want.

Comment: @ayush that would suggest that your map data frame doesn't have a column called 'long'. Are you using a map? If so, what are the columns called?

Comment: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:Data_new$Longitude, Data_new$Latitude

This is the errror its showing

Comment: @ayush can you edit your question to add the code you're currently trying to use? Please keep the question the same, but add a new bit at the bottom.

Comment: I have updated the ques. I have tried to do this with your code

Comment: @ayush thanks. I've edited your code and appended to my answer. Note that the geom_polygon was for the map. The coord_map corrects the projection. Your issue with your aesthetics is that they should just be the column names not the columns from the data.

Comment: what's the alpha here?
I am getting a straight line(Y-Axis) in the plot nothing else

Comment: The alpha is transparency. If it's set to zero, nothing will be drawn. The idea is then to use the loop I posted above to set the alpha for each point in turn and produce an image. These images can then be converted into an animation (with ImageMagick) or a movie (with ffmpeg). If you want to see all of the points, just set `p$data$alpha <- 1`.

Comment: @NickKennedy okie.Done