# How to add longitude values into a polar map using PlotStereoMap function?

Tags: r, polar-coordinates, radial

I wonder if it is possible to add longitude values to a map made with the PlotStereoMap() function. I have seen many maps that do have the longitude, but I can't manage to plot it. I've tried everything, but there doesn't seem to be a parameter to incorporate them.
Here is the map I am working with and the code with which I have achieved it.

```
PlotStereoMap(verano2008_med, lon, lat, latlims = c(-30,-90), toptitle = "SAM (+)",
              title_scale = 0.7, color_fun = clim.palette(palette = "bluered"), drawleg = F)
ColorBar(vertical = F, subsampleg = 2,
         bar_limits = range(verano2008_med),
         color_fun = clim.palette(palette = "bluered"),
         plot = T, draw_ticks = T, draw_separators = F,
         title = "m2/s2", title_scale = 0.6,
         label_scale = 0.8, label_digits = 3, tick_scale = 0.4,
         extra_margin = c(6,1,6,1))
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not using the same apckage, but would probaly be possible with `ggplot2`. There is `coord_polar()` that might be suitable for what you want. Perhaps something along the lines of these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157221/how-to-link-correctly-track-points-around-a-polar-projection-map

Comment: Another comment because I cant edit the first : This link might be helpful for exactly what you want https://egallic.fr/en/maps-with-r/  (Have a look 3/4 of the way down or so for a map very similar to yours).